# jQuery code working on Chrome and Mozilla web browser but not on Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

I have the following code on aspx file:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server" ShowFooter="true"  
AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
   <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Active" OnClientClick="return 
confirmMessage(this);" />
             </ItemTemplate>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have the following Jquery/client side code

```
function confirmMessage(obj)
{
if ($(obj).attr("text")=="Active")
{
return confirm("Convert from active to inactive");
}
else
{
return confirm("Convert from inactive to active");
}
}
```

The above mentioned code is working fine on Mozilla and Chrome browswer but in case of Internet Explorer , it's always executing the 2nd block i.e.

```
return confirm("Convert from inactive to active");
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: i have other problem like you, code work on chrome and FF and not on IE8-7

Comment: Have you tried adding an input parameter to the function `confirmMessage` that will capture the link button? e.g. `function confirmMessage(link){}` and then `if($(link).attr("text") == "Active"`.

Comment: @palakmehta can you put this line at the start inside the function `alert($(obj).attr("text"));` and see what it returns? On a side note, you shouldn't use the `ID` attribute for the link button since this will generate multiple elements with the same `ID`, use classes instead.

Comment: Hi Jsang,I actually am new to Jquery.So not sure , how to implement it with class.
Between , When I put the code "alert($(obj).attr("text"));"
with Chrome/Mozilla ,it worked fine but with Internet Explorer , it gave me "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very likely related to the string comparison differences between different browsers, as well as the differences in text-from-DOM generation mechanics. Have you tried to see under a debugger (such as IE9 Developer Tools/Scripting tab), what returns the `$(obj).attr("text")` under IE?

Furthermore, the approach of comparing texts is not highly reliable anyway (e.g. it would fail after any change in the `Text` of your `LinkButton`). I would advise you to rely on either classes or different link buttons instead, for example:

1. Use the following markup for the LinkButton: (notice the CssClass property):

   ```
   <asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Active" 
   OnClientClick="return confirmMessage(this);" CssClass="button-activate" />
   ```
2. Then use the following JavaScript:

   ```
   function confirmMessage(obj) {
        if ($(obj).is(".button-activate")) {
             return confirm("Convert from active to inactive");
        } else {
             return confirm("Convert from inactive to active");
        }
   }
   ```

When your button is not 'Activate' anymore but 'Deactivate', simply put any other `CssClass` value to the `LinkButton`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute called 'text', an ASP.NET server control 'Text' attribute gets converted to the 'value' attribute on the client side.

You need to refer to the value as so:

```
$(obj).attr("value");
```

Or more simply as:

```
$(obj).val();
```